# Pulling Data from SharePoint Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to pull data from a SharePoint List on a daily basis into a csv file. However, I do not want to use server side PowerShell to acheive this, as I am not a site administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should use the Client-side object model. There are a lot of samples/examples around SO. So you use CSOM to read the SharePoint lists and use Office interop or XML office language to create Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SQL Server at hand, you could use SSIS it's explicitly designed for this kind of task. 
http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/